# SELECT average timestamp difference in JPA with Postgres and HSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, hsqldb

I have a table with two `timestamp` columns, `startTime` and `stopTime`, and I would like to calculate the average difference of these timestamps in my table. I have a solution that works in Postgres and in HSQLDB (which I use for local unit testing) but not both, and I'm having trouble trying to figure out a common solution.

Postgres:

```
 select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(avg(m.stopTime - m.startTime))) from Measures m
```

HSQL:

```
 select avg(FUNC('UNIX_TIMESTAMP', m.stopTime) - FUNC('UNIX_TIMESTAMP', m.startTime) from Measures m
```

Is there a way to use the same query for both databases? All of the functions I've found seem to only be supported in one database or the other.

I think my main problem is that there isn't a common function to convert a timestamp to seconds in order to perform the calculation. `EPOCH` is only compatible with Postgres and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is only compatible with HSQL.

Comment: Looks like a perfect case for JPQL

Comment: That's my problem, I haven't been able to find JPQL syntax that allows me to do this.

Comment: It's always best to use the *same* RDBMS for testing and production.

Comment: We wanted to use an in-memory database for isolated, lower-level, unit-testing to avoid making connections to external interfaces, but I understand where you're coming from. At this level we're more focused on testing application logic than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem is converting the dates and timestamps down to a number of seconds. Instead of using epoch, I'll use a julian date for the date. I'll convert the julian date to seconds, then add the number of seconds since minight for each timestamp being compared. The following query does not calculate the difference, it simply converts the date to a number that's similar on both platforms .. you'll have to do this once for each date being compared. note: replace "current"timestamp" with m.startTime and m.stopTime respectively.

```
select 
(to_number(to_char(current_timestamp,'J'),'99999999999999999999')*86400/*convert from julian days to julian seconds*/) 
       + (to_number(to_char(current_timestamp,'HH'),'99') * 3600) /*Hours to seconds */
       +  (to_number(to_char(current_timestamp,'MM'),'99') * 60) /*Minutes to seconds */
       +  (to_number(to_char(current_timestamp,'SS'),'99') /*add in the seconds*/
```

Ugly as sin, I know-- perhaps you can rewrite it easier as function, but as I don't know hsqls full feature set, I'll leave it in this form rather than using a CTE or function.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that the problem here is really converting the timestamp into number of seconds, I probably didn't communicate that well in my original post. I was hoping JPA had some equivalent EPOCH/UNIX_TIMESTAMP function...that is a creative solution though.

Comment: I thought the point was to write code that would run on both hsql and postgresql

Comment: Right now I change the query based on which persistence unit I'm using...this solution seems a little bulkier and I was hoping for something a little cleaner.